# Mock GPS location on android hardware - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation

I have tried using applications like 'Fake GPS' and enabled Mock Locations in developer options to mock location. My location is successfully changed on google maps but the react native `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is still returning me my actual true location.

Also, when calling `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` after different interval I'm getting response with the same timestamp. What's the reason?

```
getLocation() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  position => {
    if (this.state.inRide === false) {
      console.log('setting start coord');
      this.setState(
        { startLat: position.coords.latitude, startLong: position.coords.longitude },
        () => this.afterStartLocationSuccess()
      );
    } else if (this.state.inRide === true) {
      console.log('setting end coord');
      this.setState(
        { endLat: position.coords.latitude, endLong: position.coords.longitude },
        () => this.afterEndLocationSuccess()
      );
    }
    console.log(position);
  },
  error => Alert.alert('Try again! GPS not working')
  // Not using third argument.
  // { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 1000 }
);
}
```

This is the console log:

[image: two geolocation calls, after different intervals]

Comment: What options have you given to `getCurrentPosition` like `maximumAge`

Comment: @RaviRaj I'm not provding the third argument of getCurrentPosition as it was causing timeout.